# Graphing a fit line through existing scatter plot

Tags: regression, data-visualization, stata, scatterplot

I've got a scatter plot of two continuous variables and they are labelled 0 or 1 depending on a third binary variable.

[image]

I would like to draw a fit line through the 0's and the 1's on my scatter plot. Does anyone have some ideas on how I could achieve this?

The current call (in stata) is: `twoway (scatter x1 x2, mlabel(y) mlabposition(12) mlabangle(forty_five))`

Comment: I suggest adding the "stata" tag to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out eventually.

You can call several graphs in the same window, but in order to make it fit the dimensions, graphing on the same variables is important.

Therefore the new call (in stata) becomes: `twoway (scatter x1 x2, mlabel(y) mlabposition(12) mlabangle(forty_five)) || (lfit x1 x2 if y == 1) || (lfit x1 x2 if y == 0))`

The `||` denotes (AND) and `lfit` is the stata call for linear fit. `if` is to ask whether y is equal to our desired value. The syntaxes may differ depending on your software.